# Powershell script to silently download from URL

Tags: powershell

I am creating a script that will check if a file is in the downloads folder, silently install if found or silently download if not found.

Steps:

1. Look in the downloads folder for the .exe file
2. Silently install the .exe file if found
3. Silently download the .exe file from a URL if not found, then silently install

I am not sure how to silently perform the above, I keep getting a window that pops up showing the download.  Here is my script, I am a beginner with PS so go easy on me

```
if ( Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\*\Downloads\7z1900.exe )
{
    7z1900.exe /install /norestart /quiet
}
else {
    start /quiet "https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1900.exe"
}
```

Comment: Is the plan to run this on your local machine?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `curl` cmdlet?

```
curl http://some.url --output some.file
```

Or in your case

```
curl https://7-zip.org/a/7z1900-x64.msi --output 7z1900-x64.msi
```

Followed by

```
7z1900-x64.msi /quiet
```

(I have used the *.msi file, since the exe does not seem to support a silent installation)

Comment: `curl` is an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest` so `--output` parameter is invalid, right syntax is `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://7-zip.org/a/7z1900-x64.msi -OutFile 7z1900-x64.msi`. FurtherMore, execution needs to be called like this `.\7z1900-x64.msi /quiet` (you can of course also set a full path - `C:\myDownloads\7z1900-x64.msi /quiet`)